# Splitting each row in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Just downloaded stock data from metatrader5 as a CSV file, uploaded it in Google Colab and wanted it as Pandas data frame.

```
data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded["@EP_H4_2010-01-03-1600_2019-12-31-2000.csv"]))
```

However, everything seems to be 1 column only and each original column is separated with /t (shown in the image).
[image: Dataframe]

How can I split column headers and each row accordingly, like in the image below?
[image]

Comment: Try to put `sep='\t'` to `.read_csv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.read_table` to do this. Alternatively you can use `pandas.read_csv(..., sep="\t")`. Essentially you need to read the file and tell pandas that your `delimiter` (the character(s) that separates your columns) is a tab `\t`.

I'm assuming you're using `pd.read_csv(...)` which defaults to the delimiter being a comma `,` which for your data is not the case.